# Object containing multiple lists python

Tags: python, list, token, nltk, tokenize

I've stumbled upon a very strange variable in Python. I am doing a tokenizing operation on multiple unicode strings as follows :

```
with open ("verbatims.txt","r") as verbatims :
    for line in verbatims:
        line = line.decode("utf8")
        tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(line)
```

& when I `print(tokens)`

```
[u'Vive', u'la', u'poste', u'...', u'.', u'Le', u'facteur', u'qui', u'a', u'la', u'flemme', u'de', u'sonner', u'pour', u'te', u'remettre', u'ton', u'colis', u'et', u'te', u'dis', u'que', u"t'es", u'absent']
[u'Une', u'honte', u'ce', u'petit', u'postier', u'fain\xe9ant', u'.', u'.']
```

I've got this strange output. It seems like `tokens` is an object containing multiple lists. Here it's just a sample but I have as multiple lists as sentences. Besides, I can't just call `tokens` as I would do in an ordinary list. I have to do a print.

The problem with having multiple lists inside the same object is that when I parse the object using a simple `for...in` loop, the parser will not work and will return only the last list of the object.

So my questions are :

- How are these kind of objects called ?
- How can I parse on this object ?

Thanks !

Comment: I suspect you are calling `print(tokens)` inside the for loop and not outside. Nested lists wrap their contents in additional square brackets, which isn't the case here. In addition, the fact that only the last list is iterated over strongly suggests you only have one list as your return variable. Every iteration, `tokens` is being overwritten, so obviously `print(tokens)` will show different things.

Comment: Are you sure that's the output of a single call to print(tokens) and not just print(tokens) being called multiple times?

Comment: Oh yeah that's right. My print was inside the loop.

Comment: However it still doesn't fix the problem which is that I only get the last one of `unicode str.` in `tokens`. I'm sure it's a problem with my loop but I can't fix that :/

Answer (score 0):

try this using encode 'utf-8' or 'latin1'

```
with open ("verbatims.txt","r") as verbatims :
    for line in verbatims:
        line = line.decode("utf8")
        tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(line)
        tokens = [x.encode('latin1') for x in tokens] # add this or try with the another
```

but if you have tokens as [ [],[] ], should do other loop in x, for example (multiple lists):

```
with open ("verbatims.txt","r") as verbatims :
    for line in verbatims:
        line = line.decode("utf8")
        tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(line)
        tokens = [a.encode('latin1') for a in x for x in tokens]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! But Akshat Mahajan was right : I was calling print() inside my loop. That is why I had these multiple lists in my interpreter

Comment: @NahidO ah? You can call print after of convert the unicode

Comment: dude, Post your txt for Help you